# Django Rest Framework: api with perform_create calls twice

Tags: python, validation, django-rest-framework

I have a code for create broadcast

```
class BroadcastsView(generics.CreateAPIView, generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BroadcastSerializer
    queryset = Broadcast.objects.select_related('owner', 'owner__avatar', 'settings')

    def get_permissions(self):
        logger.info(msg=f"broadcast get_permissions")
        perms = super().get_permissions()
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            perms.append(StreamBlock())
            return perms
        return perms

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return BroadcastNoAuthorSerializer
        return BroadcastCreateSerializer
...

    @atomic
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        broadcast = serializer.save(
            owner=self.request.user,
            media_ids=self.request.data.get('preview_id'),
            broadcasts_chat=Chat.objects.create(owner=self.request.user, type="broadcasts")
        )
        logger.info(msg=f"broadcast after save")
        broadcast.broadcasts_chat.users.add(self.request.user)
        url = STREAM_MICROSERVICE_URL + "/api/stream/playback/"
        res = requests.get(url, verify=False)
        if res.status_code == 200:
            URL_services_view = res.json()['viewer_url']
            URL_services_view_all = str(URL_services_view) + str(self.request.user.pk) + '/'
            key = UserStreamKey.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
            settings, created = BroadcastSettings.objects.get_or_create(owner=self.request.user, URL_services_view=URL_services_view_all)
            broadcast.settings = settings
            settings_ser = BroadcastSettingsCreateSerializer(settings, data=self.request.data)
            if settings_ser.is_valid():
                settings_ser.save(owner=self.request.user, key_stream=key, URL_services_view=URL_services_view_all)
            else:
                return Response({'error': "Invalid data", 'details': settings_ser.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response({'error': "Not connection to server"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        broadcast.save()
```

and serializer

```
class BroadcastCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = OwnerSerializer(read_only=True)
    settings = BroadcastViewSettingsSerializer(read_only=True)
    preview = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
...
    def validate(self, attrs):
        logger.info(msg=f"broadcast validate")
        if Broadcast.objects.filter(owner=self.context['request'].user, finish_time=None):
            logger.info(msg=f"broadcast validate error: author already has an active broadcast")
            raise PermissionDenied({'error': "This author already has an active broadcast"})
       ...

        return attrs
```

And when I call the broadcast creation api, all the functionality runs twice

The order of the logs that I see:

"broadcast get_permissions"
"broadcast validate"
"broadcast after save"
"broadcast get_permissions"
"broadcast validate"
"broadcast validate error: author already has an active broadcast"

Moreover, this does not happen every time. But I consistently get this error when making requests from the Google Chrome browser.

How can I prevent the API from being retried?